# Should I store html tags in my database^

Tags: html, database, security, tags

I'm working on an app where the users will be able to make little module extremely similar to PowerPoint. So I need to create an editor that will allow the user to stylize the text: point list, bold font, color, add and image.

The only way I found that would make the user be able to do that is that he could add tags himself.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to have tags in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine. It is just data. In a database HTML-tags are meaningless. The problem is when outputting the information. Some view engines will escape the output as the default. In this case you don't want escaping. However, it will make it vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS).